# Linkedlist contains struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am trying to make a **linkedlist** in C that contains a `struct` with data; however, I cant due to some problems with pointers. I am completely new in c. this is my code: The main goal is to write the names and store them in a linkedlist contains a struct

(I get this error error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Contacto {aka struct
>   }’ from type ‘void *’
>       enlace->contact = malloc(sizeof(contact));)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct
     {
        char name[50];
        char apellido[50];

     } Contacto ;

    typedef struct nodo {
        Contacto  contact;
        struct nodo* siguiente;
    } nodo;

       nodo *cabecera = NULL;
       nodo *actual = NULL;

      void viewNames()
       {
           nodo *ptr;
           ptr = cabecera;

           printf("**********************************");
           while(ptr != NULL) {        
           printf("%s",ptr->contact.nombre);
           ptr = ptr->siguiente;
    }

            printf("**********************************");
}



    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
     {



         nodo *enlace;
         char nom;
         int cont=0;
         Contacto contact;


         while (1){
              printf("Write names or 0 to exit ");
              scanf("%s",&nom);

               if (nom == '0') {
                    cabecera = enlace;
                    break;
                } else {
                   enlace = (nodo *) malloc(sizeof(nodo));

                   enlace->contact = malloc(sizeof(contact)); 
                   strcpy(enlace->contact.nombre, nom); 
                   enlace->siguiente = actual;
                   actual = enlace;
        }
    }

    viewNames();
}
```

Comment: "due to some problems with pointers". What specific problem are you encountering? You can't just say "some problem" and expect people to know what exact issue or question you have. Does it fail to compile? Crashes? Produces wrong result? What exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that I get this error error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Contacto {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘void *’
    enlace->contact = malloc(sizeof(contact));

Comment: Loads of issues here: scanf of a string into a char variable. Code that doesn't match itself `contact.nombre` ? malloc of non pointer variables `enlace->contact` That's enough. I give up.

Comment: have a look how he did this https://github.com/shivabhusal/algorithms_n_data_structures/blob/master/data_structures/singly_linked_list.c

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with a lot of typos, you've some problems in your code:

1. Passing a character pointer to `scanf("%s",&nom);`. I suppose you want to read a string, instead you're passing address of a character(Since character arrays are pointers internally ;) ). Then you should declare `nom` as a character array and use it that way.
2. Why are you trying to allocate memory for `node->contact` here : `enlace->contact = malloc(sizeof(contact));` 
   You've declared it as a normal struct variable(rather than a pointer) so you don't need to allocate memory for that.
3. In `viewNames()` method, maybe you mean : `printf("%s",ptr->contact.name);`. Since looking at the code you posted Contacto has got this field, not the one you're trying to access.
4. If you wanna use `strcpy`, for copying `nom` into your dynamically allocated struct, you must include [C String library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm).

I Changed your code a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //

typedef struct
{
  char name[50];
  char apellido[50];
} Contacto ;

typedef struct node {
  Contacto  contact; //
  struct node* siguiente;
} node;

node *cabecera = NULL;
node *actual = NULL;

void viewNames()
{ 
  node *ptr;
  ptr = cabecera;

  printf("**********************************");
  while(ptr != NULL) {        
    printf("%s",ptr->contact.name); //
    ptr = ptr->siguiente;
  }

  printf("**********************************");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  node *enlace;
  char nom[100]; //
  int cont=0;
  Contacto contact;

  while (1){
    printf("Write names or 0 to exit ");
    scanf("%s",nom);

    if (nom[0] == '0') {
      cabecera = enlace;
      break;
    } else {
      enlace = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

      //enlace->contact = (Contacto *)malloc(sizeof(Contacto)); //
      strcpy(enlace->contact.name, nom); 
      enlace->siguiente = actual;
      actual = enlace;
    }
  }

  viewNames();
}
```

When i run this, i'm able to see the linked list elements you took from user:

```
~/work : $ g++ testLL2.cpp   
~/work : $ ./a.out 
Write names or 0 to exit Rohan
Write names or 0 to exit Rohit
Write names or 0 to exit Raman
Write names or 0 to exit Ronny
Write names or 0 to exit Reena
Write names or 0 to exit 0
**********************************ReenaRonnyRamanRohitRohan**********************************~/work : $
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please specify the reason for you action. I'd update if i'm missing something.

Comment: Thankkks! Thats what I wanted, I am a little confused with pointers, I need to practice more